# Criação de pastas diariamente em C#

Tags: c#

Tenho dois programas distintos um do outro aqui, um deles cria pastas nomeadas com a data atual sempre que eu executo ele, dai fiz um schedule pra ele e diariamente ele executa sozinho, e o outro é para capturar imagens da webCam , o da webCam está pra abrir o diretório onde o que cria pastas está configurado, porém o usuario deve selecionar a pasta mais recente pra salvar as fotos necessárias daquele dia, o que eu queria fazer era unificar ambos, tirando da mão do operador a necessidade de selecionar a pasta.

Exemplo: O Programa da webCam cria sempre que apertar salvar como uma pasta mais recente de acordo com o dia e se a pasta já existir apelas abre ela pra digitar o nome e salvar.

Já procurei em diversos locais, uns falam que não é possivel e outros alegam que dá pra fazer sim, gostaria de saber se alguém já fez algo do tipo ou sabe ao menos um caminho pra mim começar, vou deixar o atual código do programa da webCam pra salvar as imagens e o código do que cria pastas.

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //abre a opção de salvar como, para selecionar a pasta
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif",
            Title = "Salvar o arquivo de imagem",
            InitialDirectory = @"\\MI7627\Imagens"
        };
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // se o nome do arquivo não for vazio, abre para salvar
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            // salva a imagem por fileStream
            System.IO.FileStream fs =
               (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            // Salva a imagem no formato certo
            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.picImagem.Image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    this.picImagem.Image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    this.picImagem.Image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }

            fs.Close();
        }

    }
```

Criador de pastas:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

public class CreateFileOrFolder
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData); // C:\ProgramData no Win7
        var activeDir = (@"\\MI7627\Imagens"); //caminho onde salva as fotos
        string newPath = Path.Combine(activeDir, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); //subpasta onde cria de acordo com a data
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath); // cria o diretório
        newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetRandomFileName()); 
        if (!File.Exists(newPath));

    }

    void CriarPasta(string Path)//Cria a função/void
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(Path))//Verifica se já existe uma pasta com o mesmo *path*
        {
            for (int i = 0; !Directory.Exists((Path + "(" + i + ")")); i++)//Verifica se exste uma pasta com o nome + (i)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path + "(" + i + ")");//Cria a pasta
            }
        }
        else// se não
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);//Cria a pasta
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [GetLastWriteTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlastwritetime(v=VS.100).aspx)  para obter o diretório mais recente:
Ex:

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(d=>d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```

Comment: muito bom, não conhecia essa função, valeu cara